# Can we convert this case statement to decode to calculate the shift timings in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, case, decode, oracle19c

I need to compute the shift timings based on the below time range
6 AM - 1:59:59 PM as AM  shift
2 PM - 9:59:59 PM as PM shift
10 PM - 5:59:59 AM as NTS shift
else null

Can some one help me to do the below with decode statement in Oracle 19C?

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN to_char(wtc2.actual_end_datetime, 'hh24:mi:ss') BETWEEN '06:00:00' AND '13:59:59' THEN  'AM'
            WHEN to_char(wtc2.actual_end_datetime, 'hh24:mi:ss') BETWEEN '14:00:00' AND '21:59:59' THEN 'PM'
            WHEN to_char(wtc2.actual_end_datetime, 'hh24:mi:ss') > '21:59:59' OR 
                 to_char(wtc2.actual_end_datetime, 'hh24:mi:ss') < '06:00:00' THEN 'NTS'
            ELSE NULL
            END dropoff_shift
FROM TAB1 wtc2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the minutes and seconds and can just use:

```sql
SELECT wtc2.actual_end_datetime,
       DECODE(
         TO_CHAR(wtc2.actual_end_datetime, 'HH24'),
          6, 'AM',   7, 'AM',   8, 'AM',   9, 'AM',  10, 'AM',  11, 'AM',  12, 'AM',  13, 'AM',
         14, 'PM',  15, 'PM',  16, 'PM',  17, 'PM',  18, 'PM',  19, 'PM',  20, 'PM',  21, 'PM',
         22, 'NTS', 23, 'NTS',  0, 'NTS',  1, 'NTS',  2, 'NTS',  3, 'NTS',  4, 'NTS',  5, 'NTS'
       ) AS dropoff_shift
FROM   TAB1 wtc2
```

Or:

```sql
SELECT wtc2.actual_end_datetime,
       DECODE(
         FLOOR(MOD(2 + TO_CHAR(wtc2.actual_end_datetime, 'HH24'), 24)/8),
         1, 'AM', 2, 'PM', 0, 'NTS'
       ) AS dropoff_shift
FROM   TAB1 wtc2
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tab1 (actual_end_datetime) AS
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) + (LEVEL - 1) * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2
UNION ALL
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '6' HOUR + (LEVEL - 3) * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4
UNION ALL
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '14' HOUR + (LEVEL - 3) * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4
UNION ALL
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '22' HOUR + (LEVEL - 3) * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4
UNION ALL
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '24' HOUR + (LEVEL - 3) * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2;
```

Both output:

> | ACTUAL_END_DATETIME | DROPOFF_SHIFT |
> | --- | --- |
> | 2022-01-26 00:00:00 | NTS |
> | 2022-01-26 00:01:00 | NTS |
> | 2022-01-26 05:58:00 | NTS |
> | 2022-01-26 05:59:00 | NTS |
> | 2022-01-26 06:00:00 | AM |
> | 2022-01-26 06:01:00 | AM |
> | 2022-01-26 13:58:00 | AM |
> | 2022-01-26 13:59:00 | AM |
> | 2022-01-26 14:00:00 | PM |
> | 2022-01-26 14:01:00 | PM |
> | 2022-01-26 21:58:00 | PM |
> | 2022-01-26 21:59:00 | PM |
> | 2022-01-26 22:00:00 | NTS |
> | 2022-01-26 22:01:00 | NTS |
> | 2022-01-26 23:58:00 | NTS |
> | 2022-01-26 23:59:00 | NTS |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=0afae469bd0f7f6b93e29d24b5a7f8f2)*